# How to adding another element into Jquery UI datepicker's date field?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker

IN my project, I am going to adding another element `'<span>'` inside the `date field` to display date Statistics.This is the normal date field of JQuery UI datepicker :

```
<td onclick="DP_jQuery_1291987249847.datepicker._selectDay('#igto1_whDatePicker',11,2010, this);return false;" class=" ui-datepicker-week-end available">
<a href="#" class="ui-state-default">25</a>
</td>
```

and now ,I want to adding a span inside the `td`.How can I do that!

Another problem, How can I insert the span[statistics info] into each date field when the UI datepicker was loaded.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like `$('td').append('<span>new stuff</span>');`  or one of the other dom manipulation methods here http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/